# Magmi indexing issue

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, indexing, magmi

I normally use Magmi (CE 1.9.1.0) without issues except on a recent import of new product I'm having trouble with titles not updating.

The weird thing is they show up right in the admin grid, but on the frontend and when clicking on the product (within admin) the titles are incorrect. Of course when I manually save one product in the admin the right title will show (which is a hint) but I have not found out why that is.

I've re-indexed, cleared FPC/cache used Magmi indexer etc. with no luck. It's strange because we imported another set of products after and they updated just fine.

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I faced kinda issue. My problem was when i update base image, i can see the updated image on backend page but i didn't on front site. I don't know what caused this issue. btw i just compared the updated product with not updated product.

If you have multiple store views, you have to set the title on specific store view. I think it's a bug for Magmi.